# how to lock LUKS partition from terminal?

Tags: command-line, luks

I need to lock opened luks partition from terminal as normal user.

in other words, I need terminal command do the same as `sudo cryptsetup luksClose <name>` but without root privileges.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `udisks2` to do it for you with `udisksctl` (available in 14.04 LTS and later):

```
udisksctl lock -b /dev/sdXY
```

where /dev/sdXY is the block device you want to lock (not the LUKS mapper i.e. /dev/mapper/ubuntu)

You can also unlock (open) it with

```
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdXY
```

Comment: seems like I don't have `udisksctl` utility  and I can't get it through `apt-get`

Comment: Hmm, what version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you tried installing udisks with `sudo apt-get install udisks2`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and this command `sudo apt-get install udisks2` didn't work either

Comment: In that case, try `sudo apt-get install udisks` instead.

Comment: I have `udisks` installed by default but I couldn't find `lock` option in `man udisks` .

here's the manual:http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/udisks.1.html

Comment: Whoops, `udisksctl` isn't present in the `udisks` package, apologies.

Comment: it's ok, no problem

Comment: I'm wondering how nautilus lock the partition wihtout root access??

Answer (score 2):

type in terminal:

`qdbus --system org.freedesktop.UDisks /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdX org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device.LuksLock NULL`

explanation:

`qdbus`: a communication-interface for qt-based applications

`--system`: connect to the system bus

`org.freedesktop.UDisks`: the service to connect to

`/org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdX`: the path to the object

`org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device.LuksLock`: the method to call

`NULL`: method option

for more methods from this service: http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/1.0.5/Device.html

or just type the command without a method : `qdbus --system org.freedesktop.UDisks /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdX`